# How do you pass an array of JSON objects to a Global Handler?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

I'm trying to pass an array back to a Global Handler (ashx) using `jQuery.ajax(...)`:

```
var ingredients = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rows.get_length(); i++) {
    var row = rows.get_row(i);

    ingredients.push({
        ID : i,
        IngType : TypeXYZ,
        Quantity : 100
    });
}

$.ajax({
    url: "WebServices/Calculator.ashx",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { Data : ingredients },
    success: Repopulate
});
```

However, whenever I receive these results on the Global Handler I end up with `context.Request.Params` containing a load of keys such as:

```
"Data[0].ID"
"Data[0].IngType"
"Data[0].Quantity"
"Data[1].ID"
"Data[1].IngType"
"Data[1].Quantity"
```

I would of expected just a single key of "Data" that I can then use JavaScript Serializer to convert into a useable class. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest using POST method without any JSON data type i.e. pass JSON string as data - for example,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "WebServices/Calculator.ashx",
    type: 'POST',
    data: ({ Data : JSON.stringify(ingredients) }), //using JSON2 library from json.org
    success: Repopulate
});
```

This should issue a normal POST request with single data parameter - so, on server side, you can use `context.Request.Form("data")` to get JSON string and then use any JSON de-serializer (JavaScriptSerializer, JOSN.NET) to get the object.

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript Arrays via JQuery Ajax to an Asp.Net WebMethod](http://elegantcode.com/2009/02/21/javascript-arrays-via-jquery-ajax-to-an-aspnet-webmethod/)

have look to this jquery method : [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

try the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) library.  `JSON.stringify(obj)` will convert your object to a string of JSON.